# Why is recycler giving a strange behaviour with selection?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have made an Image Editor and it works fine. Now, in my recent edits page, I added a feature select multiple items. But, I get a strange behaviour when I refresh the recycler view. See this ->

https://www.veed.io/view/43fa65a4-24e6-44e8-8cea-468ca8c62d7a.

This is my adapter code ->

```java
public class RecentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecentsAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<ImageFile> files;
    private final PopupListener popupListener;
    RecentItemListeners recentItemListeners;
    public Integer selectedItemsCount = 0;
    TextView neEditsTV;

    public RecentsAdapter(List<ImageFile> files, PopupListener popupListener, RecentItemListeners listeners, TextView neEditsTV) {
        this.files = files;
        this.popupListener = popupListener;
        this.recentItemListeners = listeners;
        this.neEditsTV = neEditsTV;
    }

    public void updateList(List<ImageFile> filesList){
        if (files.size() < filesList.size()){
            int dif = filesList.size() - files.size();
            this.files = filesList;
            for (int i = 0; i < dif; i++) {
                notifyItemInserted(i);
            }
        }else if (files.size() > filesList.size()){
            for (int i = 0; i < filesList.size(); i++) {
                notifyItemChanged(i);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            notify();
        }else {
            this.files = filesList;
            for (int i = 0; i < filesList.size(); i++) {
                notifyItemChanged(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(ItemRecentBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setData(files.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return files.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements TinyDBManager.ValueChangeListener {

        ItemRecentBinding binding;
        boolean mIsSelected = false;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull ItemRecentBinding itemView) {
            super(itemView.getRoot());
            binding = itemView;
        }

        @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "ResourceAsColor"})
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        public void setData(ImageFile file){

            TinyDBManager tinyDBManager = TinyDB.getInstance(itemView.getContext());
            tinyDBManager.setValueChangeListener(this);

            binding.fileName.setText(file.getName());
            binding.preview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(file.getPath()));

            Log.d("positionChecker",getAdapterPosition() + "");


            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String datept1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(file.getLastModified());
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String datept3 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a").format(file.getLastModified());
            binding.lastEdited.setText(datept1 + " at " + datept3);

            binding.option.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                ContextThemeWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(itemView.getContext(),R.style.Theme_ImageEditor);
                PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(contextWrapper, binding.option);
                menu.inflate(R.menu.recent_item_menu);
                menu.setForceShowIcon(true);
                menu.show();
                menu.setOnDismissListener(menu1 -> popupListener.onPopupClosed());
                popupListener.onPopupOpened();


                menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                    switch (item.getTitle().toString()){
                        case "Open":
                            Intent openIntent = new Intent();
                            openIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            openIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file.getPath()), "image/*");
                            openIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            itemView.getContext().startActivity(openIntent);
                            break;
                        case "Share":
                            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(file.getPath());
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
                            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                            itemView.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image via..."));
                            break;
                        case "Edit":
                            Intent editIntent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), ImageEditorActivity.class);
                            editIntent.putExtra("filePath",file.getPath());
                            editIntent.putExtra("position",getAdapterPosition());
                            Toast.makeText(contextWrapper, "" + file.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            editIntent.putExtra("name",file.getName());
                            editIntent.putExtra("new",false);
                            v.getContext().startActivity(editIntent);
                            break;
                        case "Remove from list":
                            TinyDBManager tinyDB = TinyDB.getInstance(v.getContext());
                            List<ImageFile> imageFiles = tinyDB.get("files",null);
                            imageFiles.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                            files.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                            tinyDB.put("files",imageFiles);
                            notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                            break;
                        case "Delete":
                            CustomAlertDialog dialog = new CustomAlertDialog(itemView.getContext(),null);
                            View.OnClickListener[] clickListeners = new View.OnClickListener[2];
                            clickListeners[0] = v1 -> dialog.dismiss();
                            clickListeners[1] = v1 -> {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + file.getName();
                                boolean deleteFile = new File(path).delete();
                                Log.d("path:",file.getPath());
                                if (deleteFile)
                                    Toast.makeText(contextWrapper, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                else Toast.makeText(contextWrapper, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(itemView.getContext(), new String[] { Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() }, null, (path1, uri) -> {
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path1 + ":");
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                                });
                            };
                            dialog.show(itemView.getContext(), "Delete image","Are you sure you want to delete the image?\nThis action cannot be reverted.", new String[]{"No","Yes"},clickListeners);
                    }
                    return true;
                });
            });

            binding.share.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(file.getPath());
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image via..."));
            });

            binding.getRoot().setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (selectedItemsCount != 0) {
                    if (mIsSelected) {
                        mIsSelected = false;
                        selectedItemsCount--;
                        binding.getRoot().setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        binding.lastEdited.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                        binding.fileName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        binding.option.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GRAY));
                        recentItemListeners.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), 1, file.getPath(),file);
                    } else {
                        recentItemListeners.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), 0, file.getPath(),file);
                        binding.getRoot().setCardBackgroundColor(itemView.getContext().getColor(R.color.primary));
                        binding.lastEdited.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        binding.fileName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        binding.option.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
                        mIsSelected = true;
                        selectedItemsCount++;
                    }
                }else {
                    mIsSelected = false;
                    binding.getRoot().setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    binding.lastEdited.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                    binding.fileName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    binding.option.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GRAY));
                }
            });

            binding.getRoot().setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
                mIsSelected = true;
                binding.getRoot().setCardBackgroundColor(itemView.getContext().getColor(R.color.primary));
                binding.lastEdited.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                binding.fileName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                binding.option.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
                recentItemListeners.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), file.getPath(), file);
                selectedItemsCount++;
                return true;
            });
        }

        @Override
        public <E> void onValueAdded(String key, E value) {
            files = (List<ImageFile>) value;
            files.sort(Comparator.comparing(obj -> obj.getLastModified()));
            Collections.reverse(files);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            neEditsTV.setVisibility(files.size() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyRemoved(String key) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAllKeysRemoved() {

        }
    }
}
```

And now my activity interface listener which are passed to the adapter ->

```java
@Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, int action, String filePath, ImageFile file) {
        if (selectedItems.contains(file) && action == 1) {
            selectedItemsCount--;
            filePaths.remove(position);
            selectedItems.remove(selectedItems.get(position));
            if (selectedItemsCount == 0){
                binding.toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                binding.toolbar.getMenu().clear();
                binding.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
                canUpdate = true;
            }else {
                binding.toolbar.setTitle("" + selectedItemsCount);
                binding.toolbar.getMenu().clear();
                binding.toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.multi_select_options);
                binding.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.left);
                canUpdate = false;
            }
        }else {
            selectedItemsCount++;
            selectedItems.add(file);
            filePaths.add(filePath);
            binding.toolbar.setTitle(selectedItemsCount + " Selected");
            binding.toolbar.getMenu().clear();
            binding.toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.multi_select_options);
            binding.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.left);
            canUpdate = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(int position, String filePath, ImageFile file) {
        if (selectedItems.contains(file)) return;
        selectedItemsCount++;
        selectedItems.add(file);
        filePaths.add(filePath);
        binding.toolbar.setTitle(selectedItemsCount + " Selected");
        binding.toolbar.getMenu().clear();
        binding.toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.multi_select_options);
        binding.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.left);
        canUpdate = false;
    }
```

And my item file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_65sdp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_6sdp"
    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_6sdp"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingVertical="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fileName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample file.png"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lastEdited"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Sample file.png"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/option"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/more_vert"
                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                app:tint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/share"
                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                app:tint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Everything seems fine here. can you post the code for item_recent ?

Comment: Sure. I have edited my question